# Das Highlander-Prinzip

Tags: translation, phrase

In einem internationalen Meeting sprach ein (deutscher) Arbeitskollege etwa folgenden Satz:

> I'm not sure if we can handle this
>   with the Highlander principle

.

Gemeint war das Motto "Es kann nur einen geben!" aus dem Film "Highlander" (gemeint ist hier, dass alle "Highlander" -- Menschen mit besonderen Kräften -- solange gegeneinander kämpfen müssen, bis nur noch der Eine übrig bleibt; wird dem Besiegten der Kopf abgeschlagen, gehen dessen Kräfte auf den Sieger über) und die Unsicherheit, ob nur eine Person Entscheidungen in dieser Sache treffen kann.

Ich bin mir unsicher, ob dieses eine glückliche Anwendung war und international verstanden werden kann. Dieser Satz setzt zunächst voraus, dass jeder der Besprechungsteilnehmer den Film "Highlander" kennt. Den Bekanntheitsgrad eines Films über Ländergrenzen hinweg vermag ich nicht zu überblicken. Zudem muss im Allgemeinen selbst ein englischer Filmtitel nicht zwingend im englischen/amerikanischen Original auch so heißen.

Schön in diesem Forum ein internationales Publikum zu haben. Wer versteht "Highlander principle" auch ohne diese erweiterten Erklärungen?

Comment: Ich habe den Film nicht gesehen, kenne aber die entsprechende Phrase trotzdem. Das eine setzt das andere also nicht voraus.

Comment: Nie gehört... bin aber auch noch nicht sehr tief im "Business".

Comment: Ich hätte es auch verstanden, halte es aber ebenfalls für eine unglückliche Formulierung in einem formellen Kontext.

Comment: Ich habe den Film (vielleicht nicht vollständig) vor langer Zeit gesehen und hätte es nur nach längerem Nachdenken verstanden.

Comment: Ich verstehe es trotz Erklärung nicht. "Highlander" ist doch ein Hochlandbewohner (Shottland? Kanada?). Da gibt es aber doch sicher mehr als einen Bewohner? Was soll das also heißen - es könne nur einen geben? Ist das ein Geistesgestörter im Größenwahn?

Comment: @userunknown Es ist eine Anspielung an den Film "Highlander". In diesem Film gab es häufiger den Ausspruch "Es kann nur einen geben!" und anschließend verlor ein Kontrahent im Schwertkampf den Kopf. Dieses zu verstehen setzt deshalb zwingend Kenntnisse über den Film voraus. Speziell der Erfolg und die Bekanntheit eines Films wird jedoch international sehr großen Schwankungen unterliegen. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass dieses auf einer internationalen Plattform verstanden wird, ist damit nicht sonderlich wahrscheinlich.

Comment: @Markus: Gut, mit dem Kopfabschlagen, das habe ich verstanden, aber "es kann nur einen geben" - einen **was**? Einen Hochlandbewohner? "Es kann nur einen Mannschaftskapitän geben" verstehe ich auch. Mir scheint, die Übersetzung ins Deutsche ist schon misslungen, aber wie lautet das mutmaßlich englische Original?

Comment: Leute, die es verstehen, verstehen es, die die es nicht verstehen verstehen es nicht... du wirst hier kaum einen representativen QUerschnitt der Weltbevölkerung oder der Businesswelt bekommen.

Comment: @userunknown »Es gibt „Unsterbliche“ unter den Menschen. Mit dem ersten gewaltsamen Tod wird die Unsterblichkeit bei diesen Auserwählten wirksam; fortan altern sie nicht [und können] nur durch Enthaupten getötet werden. Sie bekämpfen sich in der Folge gegenseitig, um die Kräfte aller Unsterblichen [...] in sich zu vereinigen und die Welt beherrschen zu können. Nur einer von ihnen kann schließlich überleben, um am Ende die gesammelte Kraft führen zu dürfen.« (Quelle: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_%E2%80%93_Es_kann_nur_einen_geben))

Comment: @userunknown Im Original lautet der Untertitel übrigens „There Can Be Only One“.

Comment: @Clemens: Heißt das, dass das im engl. eine stehende Redewendung ist, also gar nicht auf den Heiländer zurückgeht - eventuell auf den Heiland?

Comment: @userunknown Nicht dass ich wüsste...

Comment: Diese Frage ist off-topic, da sie eine Umfrage ist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sie liegen richtig. "Highlander Principle" bedeutet *"Es kann nur einen geben!"*. Es kann sowohl ein Ding sein (wie ein Unternehmen) also auch eine Person.

Comment: Danke cwallenpoole! Also wird es wohl zumindest in den USA verstanden.

Comment: Danke für das Feedback aller Beteiligten. Es hat mir sehr geholfen einen Eindruck von der Verwendbarkeit solcher Vergleiche zu bekommen. Die "ultimativ richtige Antwort" konnte es hierbei natürlich nicht geben. cwallenpool, your answer was the first, therefore I marked it as accepted.

Comment: @splattne Thanks, my German admittedly needs work.

Comment: Die Antwort beantwortet doch aber die Frage garnicht... die Frage war, ob es verstanden wird und nicht was es meint... schade, dass das als richtig akzeptiert wird.

Answer (score 4):

Verstehen kann man das sicher. Ob es sich um eine glückliche Formulierung im Geschäftsumfeld handelt, hängt davon ab, wie seriös das Meeting ist. Im Zweifel wäre ich dafür, solche Referenzen bei internationalen Konferenzen eher zu vermeiden. Warum nicht

> I'm not sure if one person can decide upon this.

Ich denke auch, dass dort ein (feiner) semantischer Unterschied besteht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe den Film als Deutscher sowohl auf Deutsch als auch im Ausland auf Englisch gesehen, bin mit der Redewendung allerdings nicht vertraut und müsste nachfragen, was gemeint ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich verstehe es. Meine Mutter nicht.