# „als …“ in Fragesätzen

Tags: grammatical-case, conjunction

Oft höre ich in der Umgangssprache Fragen wie

> Darf ich Ihnen als Experten eine Frage stellen?

Ist diese Frage überhaupt korrekt oder müsste es eigentlich ohne das *n* in *Experten* geschrieben werden, also stattdessen wie folgt?

> Darf ich Ihnen als Experte eine Frage stellen?

Ergibt dieser Satz inhaltlich Sinn? Heißt das, der Fragesteller ist ein Experte oder der, der die Frage gestellt bekommt, ist ein Experte?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] dieser Seite nehmen. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Comment: Das dürfte von Interesse sein: http://canoo.net/blog/2015/12/21/die-wie-apposition-das-personalpronomen-und-der-kasus/

Answer (score 10):

### Grundsatz

Wenn die Grundregel lautet, dass [der mit als eingebundene Satzteil im selben Kasus steht wie das Bezugswort](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/Satzteil.html#Anchor-Grundregel-3800), dann wäre das erste Beispiel korrekt:

> Darf ich *Ihnen* *als Experten* eine Frage stellen?

Soll sich der Satzteil „als Experte(n)“ auf „Ihnen“, also dem Personalpronomen im Dativ beziehen, dann muss m.E. auch „Experte“ im Dativ stehen.

Hingegen würde in der Variante

> Darf *ich* Ihnen *als Experte* eine Frage stellen?

das Nomen „Experte“ nur mit dem Nominativ „ich“ kongruieren, so dass sich der Bezug und damit auch der Sinn des Satzes ändern würde. Das wäre also nicht falsch, aber wahrscheinlich sinnentstellend. Je nach Formulierung kann natürlich auch diese Bezugnahme erwünscht sein. In diesem Fall könnte man den Bezug auch durch eine angepasste Satzstellung noch deutlicher machen, auch wenn das Ergebnis holprig klingt (siehe auch unten):

> Darf *ich als Experte* Ihnen eine Frage stellen?

### Zweifelsfälle

Grammatikalisch unklar ist das Bezugsverhältnis, wenn der Kasus des „als“-Satzteils nicht klar erkennbar ist:

> Darf ich Ihnen *als Anfänger* eine Frage stellen?

Hier kann „Anfänger“ sowohl im Nominativ als auch im Dativ stehen. Grammatikalisch ist also unklar, ob es sich auf „ich“ oder „Ihnen“ bezieht. In solchen Fällen hilft der Kasus also nicht weiter, um den Sinn des Satzes zu bestimmen. Ein Indiz kann die Nähe der Komponenten zueinander im Satz sein, was aber voraussetzt, dass die Position variabel ist. Das Beispiel zeigt die Grenzen hierfür auf:

> Darf ich *als Anfänger* Ihnen [sc. als Experten] eine Frage stellen?

Besser löst man solche Fälle dadurch, dass man auf die Satzteilkonjunktion verzichtet und die Bedeutung durch einen darauf abgestimmten Satzbau deutlich macht:

> Darf ich Ihnen – *der Sie [schließlich] Anfänger sind* – eine Frage stellen?

Im Beispiel klingt das natürlich seltsam – es geht hier nur um die Demonstration der Varianten. Je nach Sprechsituation kann sich aber auch bereits aus der Sprechsituation ergeben, worauf die Satzteilkonjunktion Bezug nimmt (analog zum „[Highländer-Prinzip](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/das-highlander-prinzip/1194#1194)“):

> Darf ich Ihnen *als Fussball-Bundestrainer* eine Frage stellen?

Auch hier könnte „Fussball-Bundestrainer“ Nominativ oder Dativ sein. Dennoch dürfte in der konkreten Situation keine Unklarheit über die „Rollenverteilung“ bestehen.

<sup>Zu all dem siehe auch die [syntaktischen Eigenschaften von Adjunktoren auf Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=383#se) sowie die Beispiele und Regeln zu [Nominalphrasen mit Adjunktorphrasen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=1087) ebenda.</sup>

Comment: Ich hab die gleiche Vermutung gehabt, angefangen, die Antwort auszuformulieren, und plötzlich war ich mir nicht mehr sicher … Aber wenn es noch jemand so sieht, ist es wahrscheinlich richtig ^^

Comment: W a h r s c h e i n l i c h ? ? ? :-)

Comment: Hier wissenschaftler; die stellen alles unter den Experimente-Vorbehalt ;)

Comment: Ok - akzeptiert ;-)

Comment: Wenn einer fragt "Darf ich Ihnen als Anfänger eine Frage stellen?", bedeutet das dann, dass der Fragesteller Anfänger ist oder der, der gefragt wird, ein Anfänger ist?

Comment: Das kann - rein von den grammatikalischen Bezügen her - beides bedeuten. Ein gutes Beispiel! Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend erweitwert.

Comment: "Thema Grips - Darf ich Ihnen als davon nicht Betroffenen dazu eine Frage stellen..." galt in meiner Schulzeit als freundlicher verbaler Knuff. Wer den Kasus nicht richtig hingekriegt hat, hat sich selbst geknufft...

Comment: Ich denke, Dativ passt schon. Das *n* ist aber möglicherweise einfach Plural, weil beispielsweise in einer Diskussionsrunde mehrere Experten angesprochen wurden - am *Ihnen* kann man es bei der höflichen Anrede nicht erkennen.

Comment: @guidot: Bei "Dürfen wir ihnen als Experten eine Frage stellen"? Bei "Darf ich ihnen/Ihnen als Experten eine Frage stellen" ist nur unklar, wieviele angesprochen sind; es ist jeweils die Gegenseite, der mit Expertise geschmeichelt wird, nicht man selbst.

Comment: Eine grammatisch eindeutige Formulierung wäre nach meinem Empfinden übrigens: Darf ich Ihnen als einem Experten eine Frage stellen?

Comment: Man könnte noch folgerichtig je einen Bezug auf beide Personen herstellen, etwa "Darf ich Ihnen als Experten als Experte eine Frage stellen?"? Gut, ginge vielleicht sogar. Der üblichere Ausdruck ist m.M.n. "Darf ich als Experte Ihnen als Experte ..." Damit entfällt die vermeintliche Missverständlichkeit. Daher stellt sich die Frage, ob diese Antwort eher normativ sein soll, oder Sprachgewohnheiten wirklichkeitsgetreu abbildet, die nicht erst durch ein Hochschulstudium geformt werden mussten. Die Nase höher zu halten als das dem Experten zu Grunde liegende Hochlatein ... naja